# Javascript array - merge two arrays into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays, one with name of the country and one with the currency type. I would like to merge these together and use the country key instead of the currencies array. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

**This is what my code looks like now:**

```
var country = new Array();
country["SEK"] = 'Sweden';
country["USD"] = 'United states';
var currencies = ["SEK","USD"];
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + currencies[i] + '" id="' + currencies[i] + '">' + currencies[i] + ' (' + country[currencies[i]] + ')</option>';
}
```

Comment: Don't use string keys with arrays. Use an object instead.

Comment: Side note use `var country = []` instead `new Array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem uncomfortable to use arrays. Use json object <sup>[json.org](http://www.json.org/)</sup> <sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)</sup> instead, this way you can take advantage of the relation key-value. In addition you can also validate it with [lint](http://jsonlint.com/). No jQuery needed. So this is the code:

```
var currency = {
    "SEK": "Sweden",
    "USD": "United states",
    "GBP": "United Kingdom"
};

(function(obj) {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("currency");
    for (var key in obj) {
        var optElement = new Option( key+ " ( " + obj[key] + " ) ", key );
        optElement.id = key; //optElement.setAttribute ( "id", key);
        myselect.add ( optElement, null);
    }
})(currency);
```

​As for the function - I think it is better to do it with objects, instead of making a string and then adding it to the select. It is an anonymous function, so it is self-contained and won't interfere with any other code. Just use it after the select is created, or place it at the end of the page.

And [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zHLDM/)

Edit:

Using add() or innerHTML - in Chrome, innerHTML is not working. And it is better this way.

As for the removing of the options - there is `remove()` method. Use one of those:

```
var x = document.getElementById("currency");
for ( var i = x.length; i > 0; i-- ) { x.remove ( 0 ); }
```

or

```
while ( x.length > 0 )               { x.remove ( x.length - 1 ); }
```

Comment: This looks good. Is there a nice way to clear the list before adding new options?

Comment: I guess myselect.innerHTML = ''; would do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common misconception that you can just use this:

```
for (var currency in country) {
  result += { ... something done with both currency and country[currency] ... };
}
```

The catch here is that hash is technically unordered in JS, so you cannot guarantee the same order of these options.

The common alternative is using array of objects instead:

```
var countriesData = [
{
  country: 'Sweden',
  currency: 'SEK'
},
{
  country: 'United States',
  currency: 'USD'
}
];
for (var i = 0, l = countriesData.length; i < l; i++) {
  result += { something of countriesData[i].currency and countriesData[i].country };
}
```

---

As a sidenote, consider this...

```
var country = new Array();
country["SEK"] = 'Sweden';
country["USD"] = 'United states';
console.log(country.length); // wait, what?
```

... and 0 will be logged, not 2 - as probably expected. Again, there's no such thing as 'PHP-like associative array' in JS: there are objects and arrays (which are technically objects too; `typeof country` will give you 'object' string).

So this is what happens here: you create an `Array` object, and it inherits all the properties of `Array.prototype` (such as `length`), in particular. Now you extend this Array with two properties - 'SEK' and 'USD'; but it's not the same as pushing these strings into array with `push` or some similar methods! That's why its `length` stays the same, introducing chaos and confusion. )

Comment: `currency: 'SEK'}` <- the closing bracket is too much

Comment: Ordering was no requirement :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var countries = {
    'Sweden': 'SEK',
    'United Stated': 'USD'
}, options = '', country;

for(country in countries) {
    options += '<option value="' + countries[country] + '" id="' + countries[country] + '">' + countries[country] + ' (' + country + ')</option>';
}
```